# Continuous functions from a topological space to itself.

Tags: general-topology

Recently I studied the theorem that states that if X is a topological space equipped with the discrete topology, then every function from X to itself must be continuous. I am wondering if the converse is true. If every function from X to itself is continuous, then is the space discrete?

Thank you.

Comment: The space can have the indiscrete topology.

Comment: So, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, any function from discrete space to any space is continuous. Dually, any function from any space to indiscrete space is continuous.

It is true that if any function on $X$ is continuous then $X$ is either discrete or indiscrete. If it is not indiscrete then there is some non-trivial open subset $U ⊆ X$.

If there is some subset $A ⊆ X$ which is not open then simply map $A$ into $U$ and $X \setminus A$ into $X \setminus U$. Now we have $f^{-1}[U] = A$, which is a contradiction, as $f$ is continuous.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you.

Comment: @416256 Hello, be sure to formally accept the answer if it was decisive in assisting your question so user87690 can be credited.